# Windows 10 - Need pinned apps to open next to its icon

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, pinning

I'm running Windows 10 and I have apps pinned to the task bar. Below are examples of what its currently doing and what I need it to do going forward. Basically when I pin an app to the task bar it puts an icon there for me to click and open that app (Duh right?). When I click to open any of these apps, I need that app window to open next to the icon I clicked. The first screen shot below shows what it's currently doing, the second screen shot shows what I need it to do. Any suggestions?

Example of what it is doing:
[image]

This is an example of what I want it to do:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally starting a pinned program should open it directly at that spot. If it doesn't happen to you, then the pinned program is likely configured wrong. For example a shortcut that uses `cmd /c program` to start a program will not work. Although this is a method to pin anything to the taskbar, it will result in this kind of behavior.

Firefox however should not have this problem. Just start the program, then right click on the opened instance and choose: Pin to taskbar. Now, unpin the first instance and move firefox to the original location.

Close and test. It should now open in place.

If you wanted firefox to start with certain webpages and thus configured different startup options, either see if you can set them from inside firefox (such as startup websites) or use a second shortcut that doesn't actually have to be on the taskbar. shell:startup can also be used, so firefox starts as desired when the computer boots.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It appears that I was pinning it wrong, though didnt have this problem before. Anyway what I was doing was pinning the app before opening it. So for example I go to Mozilla Firefox folder and right click firefox.exe and then select pin to task bar. It would add the icon as expected, but then I was having the issue I outlined in my original post. So I unpinned it, opened Firefox first, then right clicked and selected pin to task bar, per your suggestion, now it opens in the place I pinned the icon. Thanks again for the help!